# How to insert or push a schema on the main schema

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, user-registration

Hello I am new in this and not getting how can make an approach for it.

I have a **main schema** and an **user schema** in a same model file. First I am registering main schema. After registering main schema I want to register for the user schema. The registration will be done by main schema user (*admin*). So I have also created login for *admin* and creating JWT access system. By same system I want to register *users* now and want to push it on the array mentioned in main schema.

I have created separate controller for the user schema but it is creating a new collection on the mongodb.

**How can I push to same document's object's array ???**

**This is the model :-**

```
var userrSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email :     {
                type: String,
                required: "Email can't be empty.",
                // unique: true
                },
    password:   {
                type: String,
                required: "Password name can't be empty."
                },
    firstName : {
                type: String,
                required: "First name can't be empty."
                },
    lastName : {
                type: String,
                required: "Last name can't be empty."
                },
    phoneNumber :   {
                type: String,
                required: "Reqired for further contact. Can't be empty."
                },              
    verify:     String,                                 
    role: String,   
    emailResetTokennn: String,
    emailExpiress: Date,
    saltSecret: String
});

mongoose.model('Userr' , userrSchema);

//define admin(main) schema 
var adminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    companyName : {
                type: String,
                required: "Company  name can't be empty.",
                required: false
                },  
    companyID:  {
                type: String,
                },              
    address :   {
                type: String,
                required: "Address can't be empty.",
                },
    contactDetails : {
                type: String,
                required: "Company contact number can't be empty.",
                },
    admins:     {
                        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                        email :     {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Email can't be empty.",
                                    unique: true
                                    },
                        password:   {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Password name can't be empty."
                                    },
                        firstName : {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "First name can't be empty."
                                    },
                        lastName : {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Last name can't be empty."
                                    },  
                        phoneNumber :   {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Reqired for further contact. Can't be empty."
                                    },
                        designation :   {
                                    type: String,
                                    required: "Designation can't be empty."
                                    },
                        verified: String,                               
                        role: String,
                        emailResetTokenn: String,
                        emailExpires: Date,
                        saltSecret: String,//this is user for encryption and decryption of password 
                        users:[ { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Userr' } ]    
    }           
});
mongoose.model('Admin', adminSchema);
```

**EDIT :- Added main controller :-**

```
 module.exports.registerAdmin = (req, res, next) =>{    

        var admin = new Admin();
        admin.companyName = req.body.companyName;
        admin.address = req.body.address;
        admin.contactDetails  = req.body.contactDetails;
        admin.admins = {
                        email : req.body.email,
                        password: req.body.password, 
                        firstName : req.body.firstName, 
                        lastName : req.body.lastName,
                        phoneNumber : req.body.phoneNumber,
                        designation : req.body.designation,
                        role : "admin",
                        verified :"false",
                        users: []
        }; 
admin.save((err, doc) =>{
```

Comment: Are you using your model to send data ? like `const x = new ModelName({...});`

Comment: @DataHearth Yes , I have created separate controller for each like for user `module.exports.registerUserr = (req, res, next) =>{ 

 var userr = new Userr();`

Comment: try to export only the variable which contains your model and then use it outside. A model should not regenerate a collection except when you're changing the content of your schema.

Comment: @DataHearth So how can I use the user schema on child schema ? Like where will i do all the functioning ? I am not getting this one . Like I am doing same functionality of main schema . So how can I do in same function for both the schema in same controller ? I am exporting two schema separately.